# Shouldn't the Descriptions of these two tags be updated?

Tags: feature-request

The `python-2.7` and `python-3.x` tags both say that they are the latest version of Python. Shouldn't one of them be changed to reflect which is newer?

[image: The python tags, with highlights]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the excerpt of tag. You should be able to see the updated tag excerpt now. And thanks for the information.